# Why when x(t) is empty the output is ['a','b','a']. Python

Tags: python, string, list

```
def x(t):
    return '' in t

def t(aList):
    bList = aList[:]
    for i in bList:
        if x(i) == False:
            aList.remove(i)
    print aList

t(['a','b','c'])
```

The output is `['a','b','a']` where it is supposed to be `[]`.

But if I change the following:

```
def x(t):
    return 'd' in t
```

the output will be `[]`.

Comment: Because `'' in 'a'`, and `'' in 'b'`!

Comment: Do you mean the output is `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Answer (score 8):

An empty string is always "in" a string. This is expected.

```
>>> '' in 'hello'
True
>>> '' in ''
True
>>> 'a' in ''
False
>>> 'a' in 'abc'
True
>>> 'd' in 'abc'
False
```

Answer (score 3):

`'' in t` checks whether the empty string is a substring of `t`.  But the empty string is a substring of every string.  So your condition always returns True, and nothing is ever removed from `aList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def t(aList):
    print [i for i in aList if i]
```